# pyserial to ajax php jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pyserial

This is a high level question. I have hardware generating serial data every 3 seconds. I use a PySerial script to read the port and write the data to a text file.

```
    ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM3',
    baudrate=2400,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

array = [];
while True:
    message = ser.read();
        fo = open("../wamp/www/amt/test5.txt", "w")
        fo.write(message);
        array = [];
        fo.close()
```

This isn't the whole script, but represents what I'm doing. The web application then uses a ajax $.GET call to retrieve the data from the text file. I can then make the data to dance for me. (Data likes to dance)

```
$.get('test5.txt', function (data) {

var a = data.substring(data.indexOf('A')+1,data.indexOf('A')+4);
var v = data.substring(data.indexOf('V')+1,data.indexOf('V')+4);

}
```

The Problem is that anywhere between 5 hours and 2 days the systems just stops working. No feedback. The only things that fixes it is changing the name of the text file.

I assume that I am hitting a limit on the read and write of the text file. Another theory is that I am hitting the max on my memory usage and the software fails. What do you think? How do I fix this more permanently?